# Opening Gnus messages to the full height of the screen

Tags: gnus

I recently switched from RMAIL to GNUS. In RMAIL one views email messages in full screen and presses "n" to go to the next message or "p" to go to the previous one. I have also configured Gnus to use "n" and "p" regardless of whether the message is read or not. However, I would like to view my email messages in full screen, rather than having the message occupy only two thirds of the screen. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gnus's Window Layout management is quite powerful. And as always it gives full opportunity to hit ourselves in the foot. ;-)

I am not sure about completely removing the top window but definitely you can customize the default height/width of the windows. `gnus-buffer-configuration` is the variable to look for.

This is an alist with various window/frame settings. But the relevant part is this,

```
(article (vertical 1.0 (summary 0.25 point)
                        (article 1.0)))
```

Following is an excerpt from chapter "(gnus)Top > Various > Window Layout":

```
C-h i gnus RET m Window Layout RET
```

> This “split” says that the summary buffer should occupy 25% of upper
> half of the screen, and that it is placed over the article buffer.  As
> you may have noticed, 100% + 25% is actually 125% (yup, I saw y’all
> reaching for that calculator there).  However, the special number
> ‘1.0’ is used to signal that this buffer should soak up all the rest
> of the space available after the rest of the buffers have taken
> whatever they need.  There should be only one buffer with the ‘1.0’
> size spec per split.